# Openni drivers installation errors

Tags: openni, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect wiki) page to install the openni drivers and encountered following errors when i tried to resolve them.
After downloading the drivers from the mentioned link (mercurial: hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers)
I tried to
**make debian** (I am on maverick and using diamondpack version of ROS).

```
    dpkg-deb: building package `openni-dev' in `ros-openni-dev-1.3.2.1~maverick_i3863.deb'.
cd ps_engine && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/aravindhan/drivers_27_sep_2011/ps_engine'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `fix-mac-arch', needed by `patched'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aravindhan/drivers_27_sep_2011/ps_engine'
make: *** [ps_engine_lib] Error 2
```

I realised the problem with Makefile in the ps-engine and checked the contents and found fix-mac-arch file missing in the folder.
I am not sure about this patching concept so i searched for the same in the drivers folder and found it in /drivers/openni folder.
Just in order to check if things might work, i copied the file into the /drivers/ps-engine folder and tried to **make** the debian and got the below error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/aravindhan/drivers_27_sep_2011/ps_engine'
cd build/ps_engine && git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 342e334 Added missing makefiles.
patch -d build/ps_engine -p1 < willow.patch &&   patch -d build/ps_engine -p1 < disable_sse &&   patch -d build/ps_engine -p1 < disable_LogWriteToFile &&   patch -d build/ps_engine -p1 < fix-includes &&   patch -d build/ps_engine -p1 < fix-mac-arch &&  echo patched
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/EngineLibMakefile
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/Utils/EngineUtilMakefile
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/Registration.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnDataProcessor.h
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnDeviceSensorIO.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnDeviceSensorProtocol.h
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnFirmwareStreams.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnHostProtocol.h
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthStream.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthStream.h
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorFirmwareParams.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorImageStream.cpp
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorImageStream.h
patching file Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorIRStream.cpp
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/Common/Platform.x86
patching file Data/GlobalDefaults.ini
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/EngineLibMakefile
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/Utils/EngineUtilMakefile
patching file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/Platform.x86
Hunk #1 FAILED at 6.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Platform/Linux-x86/Build/Platform.x86.rej
make[1]: *** [patched] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aravindhan/drivers_27_sep_2011/ps_engine'
make: *** [ps_engine_lib] Error 2
```

I am pretty sure its the fix-mac-arch file that is missing in ps-engine and patching problem is due to the wrong path in the same file.
Did someone else face the same issue? Pls let me know if any archives are available for the same.

Thanks in advance,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11336/openni-drivers-installation-errors/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having the same trouble on Fedora 15.
It seems to me that the problem was introduced here, 3 days ago.

https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers/rev/b5dc08c27676

I actually removed the dependence, since from the description of the change, it is a patch for macs.

---

Originally posted by [Juan Saavedra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1146/juan-saavedra/) with karma: 26 on 2011-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-10-06**:
But when i launch the openni_node.launch file as mentioned in wiki page, I am getting the status as  below.                                                            "[ INFO] [1317931305.580038907]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected" .

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-10-06**:
Thanks Juan, It worked

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-10-06**:
DId you just remove the fix-mac-arch from the Makefile?